# JPA persist an entity without related entities

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, entity, persistence, persist

Supposing the following case:

```
    @Entity
    ...
    public class A {
        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        ...
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="TEXT", length=120)
        private String text;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
        private B b;

        ...
    }

    @Entity
    ...
    public class B {
        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        ...
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="TEXT", length=120)
        private String text;

        ...
    }
```

Supposing that I want to persist an A entity associating it to an existing B entity in the database:

How can I persist the entity A without persisting the entity B? I mean, I want to persist all the fields in A but only the B id in the A table, not the text of B in the B table.

Answer (score 1):

You get a reference to the existing B (using `em.getReference()` or `em.find()`), and set `A.b` to this reference. Then you persist A.

Comment: There is no way without querying the B entity?

Comment: There is a way: use em.getReference(). That doesn't execute any query.

Comment: Ok, that was what I was looking for. Thanks.